# Transaction not saving the locks?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm having some issues at work getting this to work:
I have two instances of the same application running, therefore two different spid. And both of these are going to at some point work on the same data. I cannot post the real content, confidentiality issues, so I'll mask it using other table names.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  DELETE FROM TABLE Employees WHERE Name = 'John'
  INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Age) SELECT 'John', 25
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My problem is that when the second instance of the application does the same, I'm getting an error message saying I cannot insert duplicates into table "Employees".
Why is this happening if I'm doing a DELETE just before the INSERT ? Wouldn't the isolation from the Transactions prevent one of the instances from Inserting new records while the other is being processed ?

Isolation Level = 1

Comment: What locking level and isolation level are the server/tables running?  Select @@isolation for the server wide setting, `pssinfo ( spid, 'isolation_level')` will give you the iso level for a particular spid.

Comment: Just for clarity : "open transaction" is not valid syntax in Sybase ASE. You probably mean "begin transaction" ?

Comment: @RobV yes, sorry. I was so busy hiding the real usage of the transactions that I also made that error.